# Unable to print the lines from the files

Tags: perl

It is strange to me but in the below code neither I am getting any error nor result :(

```
use strict;
    use warnings;
    use File::Find;

    my $path = $ARGV[0];
    find({ wanted => \&GetappropriateFile }, $path);
    my @all_file;
    sub GetappropriateFile
    {
      my $file = $_;

      #my @all_file;
     # print "$file\n";
      if ( -f and /traces[_d+]/)
      {
       print "$file\n";
        # push(@all_file,$file);
         open(FH, "<", $file) or die "cannot open file:$!\n";
          while(my $line = <FH>){
          print "$line\n";
          $line =~ /Cmd line: com.android.phone/g;
          #print "$line\n";
          push(@all_file,$file);
          last;
          #print "$file\n";
        }
    close(FH);
    }

    }
```

**Regx for below text files i have used ->/traces[_d+]/**

traces_com.android.phone_01-22-2014_01-15-54
traces_01-22-2014_06-24-25
traces_com.skype.raider_01-22-2014_01-15-54
traces_com.android.mms_01-22-2014_01-15-54

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is matching files like:

```
traces_
tracesd
traces+
```

Is that what you wanted?

I'm guessing you meant:

```
/traces(_\d+)?/
```

to match:

```
traces
traces_1
traces_015
traces_8675309
```

...but I don't really know what you want.

Comment: I am trying to tell thatwhen i am trying to read the file there is no ouptput comming

Comment: Does this line `print "$file\n";` actually generate output?  Is it finding files, but not reading them?

Comment: If that's the case, you might want to open `$File::Find::name` instead of `$file` or `$_`, which would be the filename without the path.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47953/discussion-between-jim-davis-and-maverick)

Answer (score 1):

If the file ends with any kind of extension like .txt or .tbl. This code wont work because trace_[numbers].txt wont be found with the regx /traces[_d+]/. If you are working on windows it is posible you don't see the extension of the files.
I recomend you to use the following pattern /traces[_d+].txt/ or something like that.

The other possibility is that the files you are trying to open are empty.